# Is it possible to upload data to Cloud Firestore via Powershell with user Authentication?

Tags: firebase, powershell, google-cloud-firestore

I can't see much online as to whether it's possible to upload data to Cloud Firestore via Windows Powershell, I know you are able to upload data to the Realtime Database fairly easily, but is this possible for Cloud Firestore?

I need to be able to authenticate a user for upload to follow the database rules and upload rather than using the service account key?

Thanks for any answers or advice you may be able to provide me with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if there is a similar mechanism as the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#rtdb-commands) for reading and writing data to Firestore as there is with Realtime Database, the answer is no, there is no provided tool for that.  It currently only provides a mechanism to [delete data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands).

You are certainly free to write your own program using the JavaScript client libraries, which have limited support for Firebase Auth and Firestore on nodejs.  You can then invoke your program on the command line.  You could also use the REST APIs for both products to write something in any language you want.